# How do I get the desired GROUP BY results for my Oracle DB query?

Tags: sql, mysql, oracle, grouping

I've just started working in an Oracle database after years of using MySQL and I'm a little confused about the grouping differences. As a starting point, let's say I have this `project` table:

| id | name | created |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Created on September 2nd | 02-09-2023 00:00:00:000 |
| 2 | Created on September 3rd | 03-09-2023 00:00:00:000 |
| 3 | Created on October 2nd | 02-10-2023 00:00:00:000 |
| 4 | Created on October 3rd | 03-10-2023 00:00:00:000 |
| 5 | Created on October 4th | 04-10-2023 00:00:00:000 |
| 6 | Created on November 1st | 01-11-2023 01:00:00:000 |

I'm trying to write a query that would give me the number of `projects` that were created within every month in a provided date range (e.g. `01-08-2023 00:00:00:000` to `04-12-2023 00:00:00:000`) in a format that ultimately looks like this:

| projectsCreated | date |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | Aug 2023 |
| 2 | Sep 2023 |
| 3 | Oct 2023 |
| 1 | Nov 2023 |
| 0 | Dec 2023 |

**How would I go about accomplishing this?** So far, all of my attempts have ended with me running into various `GROUP BY`-related Oracle errors like "ORA-00979".

If it helps, this is the query I was using to accomplish this within MySQL:

```
SELECT 
  Count(DISTINCT p.id) AS projectsCreated, 
  Date_format(p.created, '%b %Y') AS date 
FROM 
  project p
WHERE 
  (
    Unix_timestamp(p.created) >= Unix_timestamp('01-08-2023 00:00:00') 
    AND Unix_timestamp(p.created) <= Unix_timestamp('04-12-2023 00:00:00')
  ) 
GROUP BY 
  date 
ORDER BY 
  p.created ASC;
```

Thank you for any and all help you can offer.

**EDIT:**

Here's the closest I've gotten so far:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(p.id) as "COUNT(p.id)",
  TO_CHAR(p.created, 'Mon YYYY') as "createdDate"
FROM 
  project p
WHERE (
    p.created >= to_timestamp('2023-08-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:mi:SS')
    AND p.created <= to_timestamp('2023-12-04 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:mi:SS')
  )
GROUP BY p.id, TO_CHAR(p.created, 'Mon YYYY');
```

This gives me a result like this:

[image]

I've also tried this query, but it just results in an `ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression` error:

```
SELECT
    Count(DISTINCT(id)) AS "projectsCreated",
    p.created,
    TO_CHAR(created, 'Mon YYYY') as "createdDate"
FROM (
      SELECT 
        p.*,
        TO_CHAR(p.created, 'Mon YYYY') as "createdDate"
      FROM 
        project p
      WHERE 
        (
          p.created >= to_timestamp('2023-08-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:mi:SS')
          AND p.created <= to_timestamp('2023-12-04 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:mi:SS')
        )
)
GROUP BY 
       TO_CHAR(created, 'Mon YYYY')
      ORDER BY 
        p.created ASC;
```

Comment: Please show what you tried. We'll help you fix it, we won't write it for you.

Comment: What version of Oracle? Apparently Oracle 23c added the feature of using a column alias in the GROUP BY clause. MySQL has been able to do that forever, but it's a new feature in Oracle. Go figure.

Comment: Also you should use dates in YYYY-MM-DD format, but that's probably not the source of your errors. I just like correcting people. :-)

Comment: @barmar You're right, apologies about that. I added what I've tried to the question.

Comment: @BillKarwin We're on version 19, sadly. And I agree with you about the date thing, but it's out of my control. My company originated in Europe so I'm guessing that's the explanation for that format.

Comment: Take `p.id` out of the `GROUP BY` list. That's putting each ID in its own group. You didn't have that in MySQL, why did you add it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE project (
    id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR2(255),
    created TIMESTAMP
);
```

```
INSERT INTO project (id, name, created) VALUES
(1, 'Created on September 2nd', TO_TIMESTAMP('02-09-2023 00:00:00:000', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS:FF3')),
(2, 'Created on September 3rd', TO_TIMESTAMP('03-09-2023 00:00:00:000', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS:FF3')),
(3, 'Created on October 2nd', TO_TIMESTAMP('02-10-2023 00:00:00:000', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS:FF3')),
(4, 'Created on October 3rd', TO_TIMESTAMP('03-10-2023 00:00:00:000', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS:FF3')),
(5, 'Created on October 4th', TO_TIMESTAMP('04-10-2023 00:00:00:000', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS:FF3')),
(6, 'Created on November 1st', TO_TIMESTAMP('01-11-2023 01:00:00:000', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS:FF3'));
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT 
  Count(DISTINCT p.id) AS projectsCreated, 
  TO_CHAR(p.created, 'Mon YYYY') AS dates 
FROM 
  project p 
WHERE   
    created BETWEEN TO_TIMESTAMP('01-08-2023 00:00:00:000', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS:FF3')
    AND TO_TIMESTAMP('04-12-2023 00:00:00:000', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS:FF3')
GROUP BY 
  TO_CHAR(p.created, 'Mon YYYY')
ORDER BY 
  TO_CHAR(p.created, 'Mon YYYY') ASC;
```

| PROJECTSCREATED | DATES |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Nov 2023 |
| 3 | Oct 2023 |
| 2 | Sep 2023 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/0O3XYIej)

If you need to show 0 value for the months with no projects you can use below query:

```
with projects as
  (SELECT 
  Count(DISTINCT p.id) AS projectsCreated, 
  TO_CHAR(p.created, 'Mon YYYY') AS dates 
FROM 
  project p 
WHERE   
    created BETWEEN TO_TIMESTAMP('01-08-2023', 'DD-MM-YYYY')
    AND TO_TIMESTAMP('04-12-2023', 'DD-MM-YYYY')
GROUP BY 
  TO_CHAR(p.created, 'Mon YYYY')
ORDER BY 
  TO_CHAR(p.created, 'Mon YYYY') ASC
), ms as
  (
  SELECT ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(TO_DATE('01-08-2023', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 'MONTH'), LEVEL - 1) AS DATES
FROM dual
CONNECT BY ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(TO_DATE('01-08-2023', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 'MONTH'), LEVEL - 1) <= TO_DATE('04-12-2023', 'DD-MM-YYYY')

  )
  
select COALESCE(projectscreated,0) projectscreated,ms.dates from ms left join projects p on TO_CHAR(ms.dates,'Mon YYYY')=p.dates
ORDER BY dates
```

**Output:**

| PROJECTSCREATED | DATES |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 01-AUG-23 |
| 2 | 01-SEP-23 |
| 3 | 01-OCT-23 |
| 1 | 01-NOV-23 |
| 0 | 01-DEC-23 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/P2TxhmHy)

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: You are most welcome. Best wishes

Answer (score 1):

You can also use group by trunc(date_column,'MM'):

```
select trunc(created,'mm') project_month, count(*) projectscreated 
from project p
group by trunc(created,'mm')
order by 1;
```